# expected declaration before '}' token

Tags: c++

I know this error message from when there is an extra { or }. But my editor does highlight brackets and shows it matches. The problem is at the last bracket right after #endif.

```
 #ifndef PROYECTO_H
 #define PROYECTO_H


 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>
 #include <fstream>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 #include <cassert>
 #include <cstddef>

using namespace std;
namespace lulz{

template<class T>
struct Contacto {
string Cname;
string Apellidos;
string NumTel;
string email;
T sexo;
Contacto *Proximo;
};



template<class T>
class Lista {
public:
Lista();
~Lista();
bool ContactoVacio();  
void InsertContact(Contacto<T> Temp);
void InsertPosition(Contacto<T> Temp, Contacto<T>* Posicion);
void BuscarContact(string Name, string Lastname);
Contacto<T>* BuscarPosicion(int pos);
void Display(ofstream& salida, Lista<T> Cabezalista);
void Deletes();
friend ofstream& operator << (ofstream&salida, const Lista<T>& Cabezalista){
Contacto<T>* ContactList;
int Pos=0;
for(ContactList = Cabezalista.Cabeza; (ContactList != NULL) && (ContactList-
>Proximo != NULL); ContactList = ContactList->Proximo)
 {
cout << ' ' << Pos+1 << ". " << ContactList->Cname << ' ' << ContactList-
>Apellidos << ' ';
cout << ContactList->NumTel << ' ' << ContactList->email << ' ' << 
ContactList->sexo << ' ' << endl;
   Pos++; 
}
cout << "Cantidad de nodos" << ' ' << Cabezalista.numNodos << endl;
return salida;
}

private:
Contacto<T>* Cabeza;
int numNodos;
};



template<class T>
ifstream& operator >>(ifstream& entrada, Contacto<T>& Temp);

template<class T>
bool Validacion(Contacto<T> Temp);

void Opening(ifstream& entrada);
void Closing(ifstream& entrada);
void Menu();

#endif // PROYECTO_H  
}
```

It was running fine before I added the templates and added the implementation of the overloaded operator <<. Am I missing something?

Comment: What happens when you `#include` the file twice? Or, to put the question another way, what happens if you put the problem `}` before the `#endif`?

Comment: So, what is that bracket doing there right after `#endif`???

Comment: I have tried that and I get a lot of errors like T was not declared in this scope, template argument 1 is invalid and cannot convert 'lulz::Contacto<std::basic_string...to int* in assingment. So far I've always had it that way for my past proyects and always worked.

Comment: I just realized the problem might not be related at all to this. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Just move the `#endif` to after the last `}`.